# Orchard 1.8 and reCaptcha not allowing input of keys

Tags: configuration, key, orchardcms, recaptcha

I have recently installed orchard 1.8 and am looking to do a simple contact form using reCaptcha for preventing spam and bots.  The problem I am having is that the options for public and private key do not show where I would expect them to be.

[image: Screenshot of missing reCaptcha options]

Has anyone experienced this, or know where this option may be hidden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reCaptcha settings are set globally through **Settings** > **Spam** (domain.tld/Admin/Settings/Spam)

Comment: I missed the sub menu. Now I feel stupid. Rightly so, I know! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am using 1.8 Orchard and not able to save the private/public key.  In addition, i have added recaptcha to a content type but it is not being displayed with error Input error: k: Format of site key was invalid